# PyQt QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I created some shapes in QgraphicsView using QgraphicsScene. Now I want to clear only these shapes without clearing the QGraphicsScene.

```
        self.scene.addEllipse(point.x(), point.y(), 2, 2, pen,brush)
```

Can somebody suggest me how it is done in pyqt4?

Answer (score 2):

The ellipse you created is a QGraphicsItem. And QGraphicsScene has a method for removing the item : removeItem , see
[documentation here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem)

So I would suggest modifying your code like that :

```
myEllipse = self.scene.addEllipse(point.x(), point.y(), 2, 2, pen,brush)
self.scene.removeItem(myEllipse)
```